# Can my father sponsor me for Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, spain

I belong to a third country going on a Schengen visa to Spain as a tourist. But I am currently a student who wants to travel and experience the startup culture. Can my father residing in my home country sponsor me for the whole trip? What formalities he has to make for it ?

Comment: `startup culture` Don't put that in your application, very difficult to prove while you are a student.

Comment: @DumbCoder i am a student who is planning to dropout from university and start my startup as an entrepreneur ,what should i do? Should i mention that i am not a student anymore. youg guy living on dads expenses?

Comment: @BlackUser Short of a stable job, being a student who has to come back for uni is best, young guy with no job and no income is a no go. All the talk about startup culture and dropping out is also very bad, it makes you look like someone unreliable and willing to take risks, and therefore might work illegally or abscond. Down the line, having a degree is also very useful to get a long-stay visa/work permit in various countries, if your intention is to expatriate at some point, dropping out might not be the best idea.

Comment: The last thing we need in Spain are drop outs and people contributing to economic bubbles.

Comment: Please don't post your contact info here.

Answer (score 4):

> How will you prove you will come back?

That is the question you have to answer, to the satisfaction of the immigration officer during your interview and when filling your application.

As a fresh graduate with no job, you have no real reason to come back. You could happily stay in Spain as long as your father is willing to support you. However, this is not allowed - and will most likely get your application rejected, since its de-facto immigration.

Remember, the officer has to assume everyone is trying to game the system to immigrate to Spain; and it is your responsibility to prove otherwise - and it takes more than a smile to do that.

You have to provide evidence of home ties. These include a steady job, property, family (ie, you are married); business that you run, etc.

If you are traveling for tourism/leisure you also need to provide an itinerary, hotel bookings, flight tickets, possibly even other information (depending on where you are applying from and the strength of your documents/application).

If you are traveling for business, then you need to provide other supporting documents - like a letter from the party inviting you, proof that you and they have a legitimate business relationship, proof that you have sufficient funds to cover the trip, etc. etc.

Saying that you are going there just to stay for a while, maybe tour the place, and then possibly join a startup is a big giant NO - unless you are invited by a startup who is sponsoring your work visa in Spain.

To answer your question directly, if your father intends to support your visit financially, he needs to provide proof of sufficient funds - but as you are the one traveling and not your father, the application will be decided based on the likelihood that YOU will overstay or otherwise violate the terms of the visa you are applying for.